# Running a bash script that includes java commands from a python program

Tags: python, java, shell, git-bash, python-os

I have java code corresponding to a policy mining algorithm in a repository and have to execute this using commands on the git bash terminal (Using a Windows PC). I have generated test data and stored it in a file (named **temp_check**), local to the above mentioned repository. I need help in writing a python program that executes the mining algorithm using the generated input on the git bash terminal on Windows. **While the commands mentioned in the bash_script.sh run successfully when entered manually, they throw an error when called through the python program**.

PS:- The java code is publicly available and an implementation of a paper. I just need to use this code as a black box in order to get the corresponding output

I have pasted below the contents of the files I have written till now and the corresponding error messages I got.

Python Script

```
import os
import subprocess

os.environ['PATH'] = 'C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-15.0.1/bin/java.exe' + os.environ['PATH']

bash_command = "./bash_script.sh"
subprocess.run(["bash", "-c", bash_command])
```

bash_script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

# Compile
./compile.sh

# Run using the input file
./run -m ../case-studies/temp_check.abac -verbose >> temp_output.txt
```

compile.sh (Already present in the repo)

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ ! -e "bin" ];
then
    mkdir bin
fi

cd src/

if [ "${OS}" = "Windows_NT" ]; then
# on Microsoft Windows, use semicolon as a separator in classpath.
javac -cp "../lib/commons-math-2.2.jar;../lib/commons-math3-3.3.jar;." -d ../bin edu/dar/util/*.java
javac -cp "../lib/commons-math-2.2.jar;../lib/commons-math3-3.3.jar;." -d ../bin edu/dar/algo/*.java
else
# on other OSs, use colon as a separator in classpath.
javac -cp "../lib/commons-math-2.2.jar:../lib/commons-math3-3.3.jar:." -d ../bin edu/dar/util/*.java
javac -cp "../lib/commons-math-2.2.jar:../lib/commons-math3-3.3.jar:." -d ../bin edu/dar/algo/*.java
fi;
```

run (Already present in the repo)

```
#!/bin/bash

cd bin

java -cp "../lib/commons-math-2.2.jar;../lib/commons-math3-3.3.jar;." edu.dar.algo.Experiment $* 

cd ..
```

The folder structure is as follows:

```
case-studies/
   -- temp_check.abac
lib/
   -- commons-math-2.2.jar
   -- commons-math3-3.3.jar
src/
bin/
compile.sh
run
python_script.py
bash_script.sh
temp_output.txt
```

When the python script is run, I get the following error:
Error: Could not find or load main class edu.dar.algo.Experiment
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: edu.dar.algo.Experiment

But there is no error thrown when commands are entered manually on the gitbash terminal. Thanks in advance.

Comment: BTW, `bash -c ./bash_script` is needlessly starting _two separate_ copies of bash. It'd be much more sensible to just run `./bash_script`

Comment: And `$*` is buggy. **Always** use `"$@"` _with the quotes_ to pass your argument list through to a child process; otherwise entries in that list get split on spaces and glob-expanded.

Comment: Also, think about taking out the `if [ ! -e "bin" ]` and just using `mkdir -p bin || exit` unconditionally -- that way you _always_ try to create a `bin` directory if it doesn't exist, and if you fail abort the script.

Comment: And `PATH` should contain the **directory** that `java.exe` is in, not the path of the java.exe file itself.

Comment: Beyond that -- I'd suggest having your run script check whether `edu/dar/algo/Experiment.class` exists and abort with an explicit error message otherwise.

Comment: Oh, one last thing -- as https://shellcheck.net/ advises, **always** make `cd` operations exit on failure; if you use `cd src || exit`, then you don't risk running later commands in the wrong directory if `cd` fails.

Comment: And there's no reason to `cd ..` at the end of a script: the current working directory is local to the script interpreter and lost when it exits; this isn't Windows command shell where scripts are run by the interactive interpreter that called them (and thus where `cd` operations can be propagated up) unless you explicitly use `source` or the dot operator to force that behavior.

Comment: Hey Charles, I'm using a Windows system, windows command prompt is the default shell, thus I need to explicitly state the type of shell.

Comment: It would just be `["bash", "yourscript"]` without the `"-c"` if you're trying to state which shell you want to use to run the script -- and that way you'd only be running _one_ shell, not two. (It's bad practice, but... as you say, doing awful things can be hard to avoid on Windows). The `-c` is better if you want the shebang to be honored so Python can be wrong about which interpreter is the correct one to run your script with, but you're paying a significant startup-time penalty for that indirection.

Comment: iirc java is notoriously dependent on env variables.  Starting w javahome. the combination of python - bash - java looks like an experiment in fragility.  Python - java, or bash - java seems more reasonable.  Or else aggressive dumps of perceived envs at each stage, possibly w dummy Java test prog.  PATH settings in this post do not inspire confidence.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy ! Your suggestions on improving the shell code helped a lot! The actual reason was the presence of semi-colons as separator in the **run** file instead of the colon.

Comment: Heh -- I had a comment about that, but deleted it as it looked to me like you were using colons when you detected yourself as on a Linuxy OS.